# React Nav Bar Not Rerendering With New State

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, next.js

I'm making a nav bar in react that shows different links based on whether or not the user is logged in. (We use firebase for account stuff.)

Here's what I have:

```
async function isLoggedIn() {
return await UsersManagement.isLoggedIn();
}

export default class Navigation extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = ({ loggedIn: isLoggedIn() });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ loggedIn: isLoggedIn()})
  }

  render() {
    return (
        {this.state.loggedIn ? (
          <LoggedInLinks />
        ) : (
            <NotLoggedInLinks />
          )}
       } 
 }
```

I tried removing state from this component, using the function `UserManagement.isLoggedIn()` directly. That function works. I can see through print statements that it returns the proper userid or `null` when not logged in.

So what am I missing? Is there a better way to create a nav bar in react that changes based on logged in status?

Thank you!

Comment: `isLoggedIn` is asynchronous, so you can't set it with `this.setState({ loggedIn: isLoggedIn()})` directly.

Comment: a promise is an object and therefore will always equate to true in your conditional.

Comment: How do I change state if I can't use that function? @K

Comment: callbacks would help.

Comment: Ok, I will look into that now. In general is this the right way to go about making this kind of nav bar?

Comment: that's an opinion. Personally, i wouldn't use an "is logged in" method for this purpose considering you are using firebase auth and it has a more... realtime way of handling things. Instead, just have a function that runs any time the auth status changes that runs setState.

Comment: Better keep loggedIn to false in the constructor and it will be reset in componentDidMount() based upon the firebase response. This is the right way to handle authorization.

Comment: @raj That's not really a good solution because the nav bar will flash if the user is logged in.

Comment: Well the best is to pass loggedIn as a prop. But in your case since your component is already rendered and you are then checking, the above method should work fine as the flash is unnoticeable to the user.